# Eclipse force code onto 2 lines

Tags: java, eclipse

I like to use ctrl+shift+f to make the format nice looking. However sometimes I want to force code on a seperate line and prevent it from being brought into one line. How can I do this?

For example

```
MyClass test = new MyClass(1,1,5,
                           "abc",
                           2,4,5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options the way I see it:

1. If none of your code is highlighted, the formatter formats the entire class. If you want to selectively format portions of your code (e.g. not the lines you mentioned) you can highlight the other portions of code and then apply the formatter (CMD+SHIFT+F).
2. If you want to be able to format the entire class, you can enable formatter tags. On the menu bar go to Eclipse → Java → Code Style → Formatter → Edit... → Off/On Tags tab and check Enable Off/On tags. Then you can include the following tags in your code if you want Eclipse to leave a section unformatted:

   ```
   // formatted code

   // @formatter:off

   // unformatted code
   MyClass test = new MyClass(1,1,5,
                              "abc",
                              2,4,5);
   // @formatter:on
   ```

Comment: Actually I just thought of a third option. See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, not sure why someone would thumbs down such an excellent question. In VB usually you use an underscore to indicate you want code on a separate line. In Java the closest equivalent is to just use // instead.

```
MyClass test = new MyClass(1,1,5, //
                           "abc", //
                           2,4,5); //
```

This will prevent the formatter from combining it into one line and if you want you can put a little note as to why you want it on a separate line for example

```
MyClass test = new MyClass(1,1,5, // coordinates
                           "abc", // name
                           2,4,5); // color
```

Comment: Wow! I would have never thought of this if it weren't for you, thank you CodeCamper.